# How to create a dictionary of field values/counts from an observable collection?

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary, count, observablecollection

I have an `ObservableCollection<CustomerModel> Customers`, that holds a *Country* field. What I want to do is, create an observable collection of type PiePointModel. In order to store the country name and number of occurrences of that country name.

So I set up an `ObservableCollection<PiePointModel> CountryRatioCollection`, where PiePoint holds a name and amount.

Then I tried to assign that collection to my Customers, by converting it to a dictionary holding the required values:

```
CountryRatioCollection = new ObservableCollection<PiePointModel>();
            CountryRatioCollection = Customers.GroupBy(i => i.Country).ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Count());
```

But I get an error stating that this can't be implicitly converted:

```
Error   2   Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string,int>' to 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<MongoDBApp.Models.PiePointModel>'
```

I understand that this is because the Dictionary type is not the same as my PiePoint model class.

Can anyone offer advice on making query and conversion?

This is the PiePoint class for reference, that holds the name and amount:

```
public class PiePointModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Amount { get; set; }    
}
```

And this is the CustomerModel that holds the country field:

```
public class CustomerModel 
{
    [BsonId]
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }

    [BsonElement("firstName")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [BsonElement("lastName")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [BsonElement("email")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [BsonElement("address")]
    public string Address { get; set; }

    [BsonElement("country")]
    public string Country { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Country;
    }
}
```

Comment: Side note: the line `CountryRatioCollection = new ObservableCollection<PiePointModel>();` is useless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use Select (not ToDictionary) and create PiePointModel for each group.

```
IEnumerable<PiePointModel> piePoints = Customers.GroupBy(i => i.Country).Select(s => new PiePointModel()
{ 
    Name = s.Key, 
    Amount = s.Count() 
});
CountryRatioCollection = new ObservableCollection<PiePointModel>(piePoints);
```

Also notice that I used: `CountryRatioCollection = new ObservableCollection<PiePointModel>(..)` because `CountryRatioCollection` is of type `ObservableCollection` and you cannot assign here dictionary like in your example.
Constructor of `ObservableCollection<T>` can take `IEnumerable<T>` - I used it here.

Other way is use loop and add new PiePointModel to collection

```
CountryRatioCollection = new ObservableCollection<PiePointModel>();
var groups = Customers.GroupBy(i => i.Country);     
foreach(var gr in groups)
{
    PiePointModel piePointModel = new PiePointModel()
    {
        Name = gr.Key,
        Amount = gr.Count()
    };
    CountryRatioCollection.Add(piePointModel);
}
```

Comment: Okay that makes sense, using an IEnumerable. By the way you are missing a ) on the closing bracket of the piePointModel.